# Error to calculate date diff with DateTime class

Tags: php, datetime, intervals

i'm trying to use the class DateTime (php>=5.3) to calculate difference from 2 date.

The example from the manual is simple and clear, i tried that example and work good.
But if a change the start and end date, there a problem:

```
        $this->start_date = '2011-03-01';
        $this->end_date = '2011-03-31';

        var_dump($this->start_date, $this->end_date);

        $datetime1 = new DateTime($this->start_date);
        $datetime2 = new DateTime($this->end_date);

        $interval = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);

        echo $interval->format('%a total days')."\n";
        echo $interval->format('%m month, %d days');
```

Output is:

```
30 total days     //ok
1 month, 2 days   //no! i think it should be 0 month, 30 days
```

With march don't work very well! :)

Comment: My computer spits out `6015 total days`, `1 month, 2 days`. Interesting... :D

Comment: @Czechnology Maybe it considerer March with 28 days! :D I don't have tried with other months, only with Jan, and it works well like the manual example.

Comment: I've done some tests setting the date to others month, it seems to me that there's a bug somewhere. March is considered with 28 days and April with 31.

Comment: Not a bug persay.  Because a month isn't a fixed unit, it doesn't bother to try to correct the calculation for a given situation.  That's the way I read it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't there 28 days in February?  It might be picking February for the "month" unit for some reason or other.  The PHP documentation for the method seems to suggest this kind of thing could easily be the case.  Saying "x Months" isn't overly useful anyway as a month isn't a fixed unit, it could be 28, 29, 30 or 31 days.

Extract from the [PHP dateinterval format documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) below.

> The DateInterval::format() method does
>   not recalculate carry over points in
>   time strings nor in date segments.
>   This is expected because it is not
>   possible to overflow values like "32
>   days" which could be interpreted as
>   anything from "1 month and 4 days" to
>   "1 month and 1 day".

Comment: I tried with January from 2011-01-01 to 2011-01-31 and the output is 0 months, 30 days....

Comment: I'm not saying that it'll necessarily assume a month is 28 days (though it looks like it did in the main question's example) ... what I am saying is that they admit in their documentation that this kind of conversion will be inaccurate.  In my opinion, best avoided.

Comment: thx for your help! i want the number of days of the interval and luckily that works well (format(%a))....i don't understand why with Jan works well and with other no...only for curiosity! :)

Comment: I don't either, but without source code for it, we'll never likely know.  If you include January and February, what would it say then ... 30 days for a month, 59 for the two ... then if you compare 2 months and 1 day to 2 months and 1 day, should they be unequal because the months are different lengths?  a bit of a minefield really ... soundly avoided by going just for days I think, well done :)